# To do direct animation on clear super 8 mm film, can i just bleach some old film?

Tags: medium-selection, surface-preparation

I have a direct animation project I want to do using super 8mm film, but I'm struggling to find the right kind of film. I am wondering if I can buy some super 8mm film, leave it in bleach so it removes the pictures -- will that leave it clear?

Has anyone done something similar to get blank film?

Comment: So you are looking draw directly on the film? You want to bleach it, in theory, because then you can draw on it and have a white background?

Comment: yes that sounds right. I may scratch in the emulsion as well. I just want to make sure I remembered how do do this properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the gray and black light-sensitive chemicals are embedded on the film media and won't simply wash off or "turn clear" in bleach.

What you are trying to do is known as [**Draw-on-film animation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drawn-on-film_animation), but I've also seen it referred to as cameraless animation, clear leader animation, marker animation, scratch film, and direct animation. I enjoyed trying this in my early experimental-film days. It was a lot of fun and you can create some interesting experimental media projects using various techniques.

### Draw-on-Film Animation Media

Typically you start with **clear film leader** (comes in acetate, polyester/mylar) where you essentially draw or paint your animation frame by frame. Folks also *scratch* animated pieces into black exposed film and (optionally) add color later. Folks have even added hand-drawn animation ***over*** traditional black & white films, so if you have some footage available to you, that's an intriguing option.

Here are some examples and techniques to help get you started:

- YouTube (instructional video) : [**How to do Animation by Drawing on Film**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cn5e2NvvELI)
- Exploriatium (Instructional PDF): [**Scract Film: Direct Animation**](https://www.exploratorium.edu/pie/downloads/Scratch_Film.pdf)
- YouTube (amazing example): [**Process of making direct animation**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjDzdS-69w4)
- Search: [**Clear Acetate Leader**](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=clear+acetate+leader)

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is how many of the early cinematic masterpieces from filmmakers like [Melies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvhTo2-0BQg) were colored... they'd add pigments to the developed film. Very time consuming but a beautiful outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, dilute ordinary household bleach 1:10 with water, works a treat, I've done it loads of times.

Comment: Upvoted to offset the unexplained downvote. Accepted answer is wrong about film structure and I believe you when you say you have actually done it! You might want to flesh out your answer a little... do you need to wipe the emulsion off the base? etc... cheers!